# C: Passing one dimension of a 2D array results in segfault

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization, segmentation-fault

it has been a while since I wrote my last lines of C and I'm having issues getting into the hang of C at this moment. I guess this is probably a stupid mistake I'm making, but after having researched the issue for some time I still couldn't figure it out what I'm doing wrong. So this is how my code looks like:

```
int read_signal_from_file(const char* path, float* signal, SF_INFO * info) {
    SNDFILE *sndFile;
    sndFile = sf_open(path, SFM_READ, info);
    signal = malloc(info->frames * sizeof(float));
    long numFrames = sf_readf_float(sndFile, signal, info->frames);
    ...
}
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    float** signals = malloc(NUM_FILES * sizeof(float*));
    float avg = 0.0;
    SF_INFO tmp_info;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_FILES; i++) {
        read_signal_from_file(INPUT_FILES[i], signals[i], &tmp_info);
        for(long j = 0; j < tmp_info.frames; j++) {
            printf("Sample no #%ld: %f\n", j, signals[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

inside of `read_signal_from_file()`, I have no troubles accessing the allocated memory portion. But as soon as I'm trying to access it from the scope of the main function (e.g. as in the printf() example above, I get corrupted results that look suspiciously like uninitialized memory or overflows. If I try to operate on that data, (e.g. by calling `vDSP_meanv()`, the application crashes with a segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have a 2D array, you have a pointer-to-pointer.

Then, the pointers themselves don't point to anything, they are uninitialized because you don't allocate memory for them - thus your program invokes undefined behavior.

So, either allocate memory for them using `malloc()` in a for loop, or even better, use a real array:

```
float (*arr)[COLUMN_SIZE] = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * ROW_SIZE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I feel quite silly having asked such a stupid question, but thanks to you I won't be making that mistake again :)

Comment: @maxPlauth Don't worry, there are way worse questions on SO. Like, orders of magnitudes worse (when OP doesn't even have a minimal idea about what he is doing). Yours is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating the array of pointers, but you aren't setting them to anything:

```
float** signals = malloc(NUM_FILES * sizeof(float*));
```

Which means that you are passing an uninitialized pointer (`signals[i]`) here:

```
read_signal_from_file(INPUT_FILES[i], signals[i], &tmp_info)
```

Because `signals[i]` is passed by value, it isn't going to be changed in the function call, so it is still going to be uninitialized after `read_signal_from_file` returns.

A simple change would be to pass by reference:

```
int read_signal_from_file(const char* path, float* &signal, SF_INFO * info) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

(As mentioned) You are allocating the `signals` array of pointers, but you don't assign the pointers in this array. When you allocate `signal` in `read_signal_from_file` you do reserve the memory but you're assigning the pointer to the *local* `signal` variable. If you want to assign the allocated `signal` to the `signals` array in your `main` function you should pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
read_signal_from_file(INPUT_FILES[i], &signals[i], &tmp_info);
```

and change your `read_signal_from_file` function to accept it:

```
int read_signal_from_file(const char* path, float ** signal, SF_INFO * info) {
    // ...
    *signal = malloc(info->frames * sizeof(float));
    // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass `float *signal` to `read_signal_from_file()` and reassign `signal` there but that just changes the local var `signal`, not `signals[i]` in `main()`. 
Change the signature of `read_signal_from_file()` to

```
int read_signal_from_file(const char* path, float** signal, SF_INFO * info)
```

change your `malloc()` to

```
*signal = malloc(info->frames * sizeof(float));
```

and pass `signals+i` instead of `signals[i]`